# visual basics equal to or greater than

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to write some code that says if `textbox1` is equal to 0 between 10 then HandDecimal = 1. Else if `textbox1` is equal to 10.1 through 100, then HandDecimal = 3. Else if `textbox1` is equal to 100.1 and greater than HandDecimal = 5.

Here is my code, but it does not seem to work for me.

```
        If WeightDecimal = 0 <= 10 Then

            HandDecimal = 1

        ElseIf WeightTextBox.Text = 10 <= 100 Then

            HandDecimal = 3

        ElseIf WeightTextBox.Text >= 100.1 Then

            HandDecimal = 5

        End If
```

How do I have to change the code to make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
   Dim weight as Decimal = Decimal.Parse(WeightTextBox.Text) 
   If weight  >= 0 AndAlso weight <= 10 Then

        HandDecimal = 1

    ElseIf weight  > 10 AndAlso weight <= 100 Then

        HandDecimal = 3

    ElseIf weight > 100 Then

        HandDecimal = 5

    End If
```

Answer (score 4):

`Select Case` statement with `To` operator

```
Select Case WeightDecimal
Case 0 To 10
    HandDecimal = 1
Case 10.1 To 100
    HandDecimal = 3
Case Else 
    HandDecimal = 5
End Select
```

Comment: thank you very much, would have not guessed that, and thanks to everyone else who submitted answers.

Comment: Sorry @WilliamDuron but I think this is a flawed solution. What happens when your input is "10.09"? I think you'd expect `HandDecimal` to be 3, or even 1, but it will actually be 5.