# Operator '<=' not defined for types 'Integer' and 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'

Tags: vb.net, syntax-error

Here is the code I am trying:

```
If txtMonths >= 1 And txtMonths <= 6 Then
    additionalDiscount = 0
```

Comment: apparently "intmonths" is a textbox.  that means it is an control - an object - not a simple integer variable

Comment: check this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638541/visual-basics-equal-to-or-greater-than

Comment: Sorry guys I messed up. I meant to write txtMonths.

Comment: Please make sure that you have `Option Explict` and `Option Strict` both turned on by default. They will save you a lot of coding errors.

Comment: That doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 4):

`intMonths` is a `TextBox`, not an `int`, so you can't just use it as an `int`. You'd have to extract its textual value and convert it to an `int` first:

```
Dim intMonthsVal As Integer = Integer.Parse(txtMonths.Text)
If intMonthsVal >= 1 AndAlso intMonthsVal <= 6 Then
    additionalDiscount = 0
End If
```